# How to delete an invalid character from a tkinter entry widget

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry, python-3.9

I am trying to validate the input of an entry  widget, so that only digits (0-9) may be entered. If the user presses an invalid key (e.g. a 'j') I want the widget to silently ignore the input.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def on_key_integer(event, var):
    """ Ensures that the key pressed is an numeric value 0-9"""
    """ user can use any numeric key """
    """If they use a non-numeric key this should be removed silently, as if they had not                                pressed it """
    currentPosition = event.widget.index("insert")
    print(f"The value of the variable is: {var.get()}")
    print(f"The key '{str(event.char)}' was pressed at position {currentPosition}")
    if str(event.char) not in [str(x) for x in range(0,10)]:    # builds a list of str versions    of numbers 0-9
        print("The key pressed is non-numeric")
        # delete the character entered
        event.widget.delete(currentPosition-1)


root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Dog data entry form")
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
variables=dict()
ttk.Label(root, text = "Dog data entry", font = ("Verdana", 16)).grid()

ttk.Label(root, text="Dog's Age").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, sticky="e")
variables["Dog Age"] = tk.StringVar()
variables["Dog Age"].set('')
dog_age=ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=variables["Dog Age"])
dog_age.bind("<Key>", lambda event, v=variables["Dog Age"] : on_key_integer(event, v))
dog_age.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(tk.E+tk.W))
dog_age.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

What happens is that the code allows any digits to be retained. If I enter a 'j', or any other invalid character then that character remains, but the previous character is removed (deleted). I tried to delete using currentPosition, rather than currentPosition-1, and nothing is deleted from the entry field. Can anyone explain what is happenning and how I might resolve this.

Thanks in advance (by the way, this is being used as a teaching tool)

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting it, you should prevent it from being inserted in the first place. The Entry widget has support for that. See [Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4140437/7432)

Comment: @BryanOakley really appreciate you pointing me to this post, it took me about half an hour to work out how to apply the code and I have started to go through the documentation in more detasil!